# Python use same selenium driver instance in different objects

Tags: python, selenium, oop, selenium-webdriver

i'm quite new to python. For a psychology project i wrote a little app to collect posts from  forums with beautifulsoup (and requests to get the source code of the webpages). Some forums need a login. So i changed my app to do this task with selenium.
But i can't figure out how to use the same driver-instance in different classes which are in different files resp. modules. In my PyCharm-Project I added the following class in a extra module:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class SetDriver():
    def __init__ (self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def setUp():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        return SetDriver(driver)
```

But if i want to access the instance from my main file or another module for example with this code:

```
actualsite = "a forum url"
driver = crawler.SetDriver.setUp()
driver.get(actualsite)
```

I get this error:
AttributeError: 'SetDriver' object has no attribute 'get'

I'm pretty sure that i do have a problem with my understanding of OOP here, but after searching the web for a couple of hours now, i couldn't figure out what i do wrong.

Looking forward for some help =)
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the selenium driver is assigned to the the `driver` attribute of the SetDriver() class. So you would have to use that attribute whenever you want to reference the driver:

```
# This should work

actualsite = "https://www.duckduckgo.com"
driver = crawler.SetDriver.setUp()
driver.driver.get(actualsite)
```

in the above code, the first `driver` is your `SetDriver()` instance, which is not the actual selenium driver. The actual selenium driver is in the `driver` attribute on that class. You can confirm that by checking the `type()` of the variables you have created.

```
actualsite = "https://www.duckduckgo.com"
driver = crawler.SetDriver.setUp()

# check `driver` type
print(type(driver))

# check `driver.driver` type
print(type(driver.driver))
```